# How do I move tick labels closer to x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to consolidate down this graph so that I can put it (and others) into a powerpoint slide with it still legible. It'd be a huge help if I could move the labels for the x axis closer to the ticks, but I can't figure out how to do so.

I've added in some dummy data, but in the real file those would be dates - not sure if that matters or not, but I thought I'd mention it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D

tva_blue = '#003A70'
lt_grey = '#BFBFBF'
green = '#00B050'
median = '#7F7F7F'
black = '#000000'

x = [10, 20, 30,40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
y = [8, 5, 3, 6, 8, 6, 2, 9]
z = [11, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7]

dates.ConciseDateConverter(x)

labels = x

tfont = {'font': 'arial', 'size': 6.5, 'fontweight': 'bold'}
lfont = {'font': 'arial', 'size': 6, 'fontweight': 'bold'}

#Set Chart Size
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (2, 1) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_dpi(400)

# Find Min / Max, use to set y axis dimensions
mx = math.ceil(12)
ymin = round(8)

# Generate Bar Chart with Line interse
plt.bar(x, y, color = tva_blue, width = 20, align = 'center', label = 'Retail Rate (¢/kWh)')
plt.plot(x, z, color = green, lw = 1.5, label = 'Top Quartile')

# Place Date labels onto x axis
plt.xticks(x, labels, fontsize = 5, rotation='vertical')
plt.yticks(y, fontsize = 5)


# Set y axis parameters
plt.ylim(8, (mx))
plt.ylabel("Cents / kWh", fontdict = lfont)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

#Add title to chart
plt.title('TVA Effective Retail Rate \n 12-Month Rolling Average Trends \nTVA Rate Gap to Top Quartile Utility Co. Peers'
, fontdict=(tfont), fontname = 'Arial', y = 1.32, color = 'black')

# Hide top, right spines
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)

# Center Ticks, Pad margins
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=16))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', tick1On=True, tick2On=False, 
               length = 3)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', tick1On=False, tick2On=False)
for label in ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True):
    label.set_horizontalalignment('center')
ax.margins(x=0.013)

# Format left and bottom axes
for axis in ['left', 'bottom']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(.7)
    ax.spines[axis].set_color(black)

# Format Legend Line Width
def update(handle, orig):
    handle.update_from(orig)
    handle.set_linewidth(2.5)

# Format Legend Location
plt.legend(handler_map={plt.Line2D : HandlerLine2D(update_func=update)}, 
           ncol = 2,  bbox_to_anchor = (0.5, 1.40), loc = 'upper center', 
           frameon = False, fontsize = 5)

# Generate chart    
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you're going to put this in Powerpoint anyways, the quick and dirty way is just to edit the image there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `pad` to 0 (or even a negative value) for your major x-axis:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', tick1On=False, tick2On=False, pad=-3)
```

This will give you (tiny picture because of figsize (2, 1)):

[image]